# Understanding when a vector is parallel vs. perpendicular?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, plane-geometry

I am having some difficulty with this concept. I am studying a problem:

> Find an equation for the plane that passes through the point $P = (1, 2, 3)$
>   and contains the line $L$ given by the parametric equation
>   $x(t) = 1 − 3t,\, y(t) = 3$, and $z(t) = 6 + 2t$.

The solution states that $v = \left< 3, 0, −2 \right>$ is parallel to $L$ and hence the plane. $Q = (1, 3, 6)$ is in the plane and
hence $PQ = \left< 0, 1, 3 \right>$ is parallel to the plane.
$n = v \times PQ = \left< −2, 9, −3 \right>$ is perpendicular to the plane.
Therefore, the plane is $−2x + 9y − 3z = −2 \cdot 1 + 9 \cdot 2 − 3 \cdot 3 = 7$.

Could someone help me with this reasoning? I understand $v$ is parallel to $L$ because it is a scaled version of the normal to $L$, where the normal is $\left< -3, 0, 2 \right>$. I understand why $Q$ is in the plane.

Why is $PQ$ parallel to the plane? Why do we know that $v \times PQ$ will be perpendicular to the plane? Is this because the cross product of two vectors parallel to a plane will be perpendicular to the plane? Thank you for any clarification or help in advance! Just trying to get a better hold on this concept.

Comment: Yes, I get that part.

Comment: Why is $PQ$ parallel to the plane? Try drawing a little sketch, even in two dimensions of a plane (a line) with two points on it, $P$ and $Q$, and then consider the line from $P$ to $Q$ and then the *vector* $PQ$ is the translate of that line to be starting from the origin and hopefully you will see why this vector is then parallel to the plane

Comment: and your comment about $v \times PQ$ being perpendicular because the cross product of two vectors parallel to the plane will indeed give a new vector that is perpendicular to them both, and so perpendicular to the plane

Comment: $P$ is in your plane, $Q$ is on $L$ and $L$ is in your plane.  Therefore $Q$ in in the plane and $\vec {PQ}$ is parallel to your plane.  The cross product of two independent vectors parallel to the plane is perpendicular to your plane.

Comment: I get that P is in the plane and Q is on L--why does this mean Q is in the plane?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, $v$ isn’t *normal* to $L$. That’s pretty much the opposite of being parallel. In vector form, the given parameterization of the line is $\langle1,3,6\rangle+t\langle-3,0,2\rangle$ from which it should be obvious that $Q=(1,3,6)$ is a point on the line (for $t=0$) and $v=\langle-3,0,2\rangle$ is the line’s direction vector, so is by definition parallel to $L$.

The points $P$ and $Q$ are on the plane, so the line segment $\overline{PQ}$ is also contained in the plane. The vector $Q-P$ (what you’re calling $PQ$) is parallel to this line segment, which means that it is also parallel to any plane that contains the line segment.

Finally, the cross product of two vectors is perpendicular to them both. Since both of the vectors are parallel to the plane you’re constructing, their cross product will also be perpendicular to that plane.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared up some questions. Why is that v is parallel to the plane though? if the plane contains the line L then wouldn't the direction vector of L be perpendicular to the plane?

Comment: @user3293643 Not at all. The direction vector of $L$ is *parallel* to $L$ and since $L$ is in the plane is also parallel to that plane.

Comment: Thanks--I am a little confused. I was taught that in a plane the direction vector is perpendicular--e.g., for the plane 2x−y+3z=82x−y+3z=8, the perpendicular vector is (2,−1,3)(2,−1,3). Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @user3293643 Whoever called a perpendicular vector to a plane its “direction vector” might have done you a disservice. It does determine the plane’s “direction” (in $\mathbb R^3$) in a sense, but does so in a different way than a direction vector for a line. If you call the former the plane’s “normal” instead, that might help you keep the two concepts clear.

Comment: Thanks! So the "normal" vector is perpendicular to the plane it describes but the direction vector is parallel to the line it describes? Also if one multiples the normal vector of a plane by a constant, does that still constitute a normal to the plane?

Comment: @user3293643 You’ve got it. Multiplying a vector by a nonzero constant doesn’t change its direction, so any nonzero multiple of a normal vector is also a normal. Often, you’ll use a *unit normal* with length equal to one for convenience.